# measurable function and monotone

Tags: measure-theory, functions

I'm in computer science and work with verification of program properties using the theory of imprecise probabilities which mixes functions, measurability and set-theory.

I have three definitions which I need to relate and am not sure how they are connected, please help. It is a bit backwards, I'm starting with a set function and needs to deduces whether it is measurable.

As I understand it, a function $f \colon (X,\mathcal{X}) \rightarrow (Y,\mathcal{Y})$ is *measurable* if $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{X}$ whenever $B \in \mathcal{Y}$.

Let $f$ be a function from sets to sets $f \colon \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$   where $(X,\mathcal{X})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{Y})$ are measurable sets. 
Such a function $f$ is:

- *monotone* if $A \subseteq B \Rightarrow f(A) \subseteq f(B)$ whenever $A,B \in \mathcal{X}$
- *distributive* if $f(A \cup B) = f(A)\cup f(B)$ whenever $A,B \in \mathcal{X}$

**Proposition:** *If a function is distributive, then it is monotone.*

The opposite is not true (e.g. let $f$ be defined as $f(A)=A'$, $f(B)=B'$, and $f(A \cup B) = A'\cup B'\cup C'$ where $C' \neq \emptyset$. $f$ is monotone, but not distributive.).

Ok, that should be the definitions, now for the question.

**Edited:** as pointed out it does not make sense to ask whether a set function is measurable. Instead I would like to know how monotone and distributive is linked to measurable functions.

Let $f \colon (X,\mathcal{X}) \rightarrow (Y,\mathcal{Y})$ be a measurable function.

Is $f: \mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ necessarily monotone?

If $f$ is monotone is it then distributive?

Any hints of how to prove or disprove these three statements will be helpful.

Comment: How are you defining measurability for a function $g : \mathcal X \to \mathcal Y$?

Comment: I was thinking something along $g: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ is measurable if there exist a measurable space $(Z,\mathcal{Z})$ where $\mathcal{Z} \subseteq \mathcal{Y}$ such that there exist a function $g: \bigcup \mathcal{X} \rightarrow Z$ and $g^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{X}$ whenever $B \in \mathcal{Z}$

Comment: A function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ is measurable iff  $\{f^{-1}V: V\in \mathcal Y\}\subset \mathcal X.$.... But it doesn't mean anything to ask whether a function from  $\mathcal X$ to $\mathcal Y$ is measurable.

Comment: You are right. But I need to tell whether a probability measure for the $(X, \mathcal{X})$ would be carried by $g$ to some measurable space. Eg. Let $X$ be finite and If $g: \wp(X) \rightarrow \wp(X)$ is defined by a function $g': X \rightarrow X$ such that $g(A) = {g'(x) \in X \mid x \in X}$ -will the output of $g$ be describable by a probability measure over $(Z, \mathcal{Z})$ where $Z \subset X$?

Comment: Hmm..  I can manage if we can look at the distributive and monotone properties for a measurable function..  Any ideas?